# Can a customer sue an Internet Cafe for being BULLied (kicked out+ threatening to call the SECURITY)

Tags: restaurants, public-accommodations

This internet cafe (computer gaming, charging us for every hour) literally kicked me out on the 3rd time (meaning I've only been there twice before)
for "having too many complaints" and "we can do that because we're a small business"

Here’s the most possible reason that they hate me: helping me adjust the settings and then switch stations  took a long time (about 10 minutes, which is long for an anxious game player when he’s reluctantly AFK…you guys know how that feels) to try changing the game setting (but FAILED), and then I have to be brave enough to ask them  if they can let me switch seats. Relaunching the game also takes time, which is counted into the $5/ hour.

I stayed for about 71 minutes, which is a little longer than the standard time. When I was about to leave and pay, I asked them if they could charge me for just an hour because of the time wasted. They agreed, but became upset  when I carelessly dropped 2 drop of hand sanitizer on the table.

And now the main story happens: on this 3rd time, that woman straightforwardly said “I’m asking you nicely, to leave” and I was shocked.

Anyway that woman refused to provide any reason for kicking me  She never let me complete the sentence  and kept saying that she would call the SECURITY if I don’t leave

So I got kicked out because I had “too many complaints” and they’re “small business who can refuse to Service”.

That’s the whole story. I searched for a while and saw that “a store can ban you or anyone else for any reason except those protected by law against discrimination”.  Does that mean I can’t sue them with a reasonable chance to win?

Comment: tl;dr: Can I sue a store that told me to leave because I was annoying the employees?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's clearly another side to the story.  I'm sure you feel like a victim, but you likely did something to trigger such an action and there is no way to even form an impartial opinion from a single, rambling and biased recounting of the incident.

Comment: @Michael Hall
 That may be, but then it isn't our place to say what justice or ethics demand in this specific case. We **can** indicate what the law requires or permits in this **kind** if situation. And we should. So IMO this should stay open.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, I would agree and retract my close vote if it was given a dramatic trimming.  For example, what does the big bearded guy staring at the OP have to do with any of this?!  But then it would probably be a dupe…

Comment: @Michael Hall Now that this has been closed, the only way to retract your close vote is to vote to reopen it. I have edited the question down by quite a bit.

Comment: @DavidSiegel  Which I will be happy to do when the whining rant nature of the question is edited out.  But then I might revote  to close as a dupe because I’m sure there are many similar questions about private business’ rights to exclude customers who violate conduct rules.  It actually seems like one of the staples here, a close second to copyright questions…

Comment: E.g, What does shamefully cleaning drops of hand sanitizer have to do with the root question?  I’m not against some background narrative to provide context and make for a more interesting read, but this is really nothing more than a very one sided “poor me” story thinly disguised as a legal question in an oft repeated theme…

Comment: What is the jurisdiction this happened in?

Answer (score 4):

There is, in most countries at least, no law requiring a business to treat a customer fairly. In general, a business may refuse to serve a would-be customer for any reason or none, provided that the reason is not membership in a protected class (racial, religious, ethnic, or sexual bias, mostly). Exactly which classes are protected depends on the local law (in the US, there can be such laws at all of federal, state, and municipal levels).

If a customer is asked to leave and does not do so, s/he could be charged with defiant trespass (or local equivalent). More likely, security, or the police, could simply escort the customer out of the business, using as much force as is reasonably needed for that purpose.

Unless there are grounds for action not mentioned, I see no basis for a successful suit by the customer.

Comment: > There is, in most countries at least, no law requiring a business to treat a customer fairly. why is that ?

Comment: They are required to treat them in a legal way. The business is not allowed to punch him, throw coffee over him and similar. There are many ways to treat people unfair that are not illegal.

Comment: @IndianLawApplicant Because the legislatures of various countries have not seen fit to pass such laws.. They could if they so chose. Because a business traditionally has a right to deal or not deal with customers as the owner wishes.

Comment: @gnasher729 That is true, and does not contradict anything I wrote in the answer above, as I see it.

Comment: I read gnasher’s comment as a response to the first comment, not your answer.

Comment: I see but are there any examples of countries where customers have fair treatment rights ? it seems weird to think this wouldn't exist. and kinda scary

Comment: @IndianLawApplicant, the trouble is that "fair" can be subjective and very much depends on which side of the argument you are on.  This question is a good case in point; even though the OP feels they were treated unfairly, in their own words the business apparently had received multiple complaints about them, and even "asked them nicely to leave".  It seems that if the behavior was disturbing to other customers the owner/manager would need to be "fair" to them also, right?